# How to recognize automatically a formula in R?

Tags: r

Let's assume the following data.frame

```
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)
```

Let's now assume that some user input, leads to the following variable

```
z <- "x + 0.25 * y"
```

where z is a character, but intended to be interpreted as a formula.

```
d$z <- d$x + 0.25 * d$y
```

For regression, the conversion is straightforward with as.formula(), but here I want it to apply to a DF column. The gas-factory method would be to split and identify each separator and translate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `eval` and use the environment of 'd'

```
eval(parse(text = z), d)
#[1]  3.75  5.00  6.25  7.50  8.75 10.00 11.25 12.50 13.75 15.00
```